# How to get the video player to work on react native on expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, video-player

I have been trying to get Expo react native video player to work. 
But I always get this error

```
TypeError: TypeError: (0, _netinfo.useNetInfo) is not a function. (In '(0, _netinfo.useNetInfo)()', '(0, _netinfo.useNetInfo)' is undefined)
```

I have followed this link to install the library https://github.com/ihmpavel/expo-video-player , and I installed the dependencies mentioned. 
Note: During the installation of the dependency @react-native-community/netinfo, I got the following warnings:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I need your help guys to solve this issue, Thanks in advance.